# Erro de View view

Tags: java, android

Estou com esta sistema de consulta no banco de dados msql do no site, mas quero levar para a oura activity os valores de login e senha. tentei com `putExtra`, mas ela não reconhece as Strings `user_name` e `password`. Como faço para obter os valores de `user_name` e `password` e enviar para outra activity?

segue código:

MainActivity (apenas o comando de ação)

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //pega os textos escritos
               String username = editText1.getText().toString();
               String password = editText2.getText().toString();
               String type = "login";
               BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(MainActivity.this);
               backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);



            }
        });
```

Segue Código do BackgroundWorker.java

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

Context context;



AlertDialog alertDialog;

BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];

    String login_url = "http://www.ic.eng.br/login.php";

    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {

            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];

            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }




    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Status do login");

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();

    if(result.equals("Conectado")){

            // aqui o redirecionamento para a activity


                Intent i = new Intent(context, Principal.class);
                i.putExtra("login", user_name);
                i.putExtra("senha", password);

                context.startActivity(i);


            } else {
                // quando as credenciais estão incorretas
            }

}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

O jeito mais fácil é colocar na Intent via putExtra e pegar na activity iniciada, vi que você está fazendo isso mas não tem o código da segunda activity onde você recupera os valores, pode postar ela? De qualquer modo o jeito de passar e pegar o valor é assim:

Passando o valor:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
//EXTRA_SESSION_ID é a key que será usada para recuperar o valor que foi passada em sessionId
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent);
```

Pegando o valor na outra activity:

```
String sessionId= getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

Retirado e adaptado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/6009128

Comment: Não esta dando certo porque não estou conseguindo transportar a String para onPostExecute. Como não consegui uma forma, estou usando o SharedPreferences na MainActivity e deu certo. Mas obrigado...